# Mersenne semiprimes with square indices

Tags: elementary-number-theory, semiprimes

A Mersenne semiprime is a semiprime of the form $2^n-1$, it can be shown that $2^n-1$ can be a semiprime if and only if $n$ is either a prime or a square of a prime. There are plenty  Mersenne semiprimes with prime indices $n$, but Mersenne semiprimes with square indices are very rare, only three are known to date: $2^4-1,  2^9-1,$  and $2^{49}-1.$ So where is the next square index $n$?

Comment: Fairly sure this is an open problem.  See here, for example: http://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=14249

Comment: Necessary is that the index is a square of a prime $p$ , such that $2^p-1$ is a Mersenne prime.

Comment: @Peter, $2^{11}-1=23\cdot 89$